# Simple translation from bash to perl - Bitcoin private key import format

Tags: perl, bash, bitcoin

I'm working on a Bitcoin brain wallet generator in Perl.
I wasn't able to make the last step correctly (base58 encode) to generate the private key (import format).

I have found a very simple bash script that does the job, and I will like to have it translated to Perl so I can make the key generation entirely on Perl.

Can someone help me to translate the following bash code to a Perl sub?

```
#!/bin/bash
base58=({1..9} {A..H} {J..N} {P..Z} {a..k} {m..z})
bc <<<"ibase=16; n=${1^^}; while(n>0) { n%3A ; n/=3A }" |
tac |
while read n
do echo -n ${base58[n]}
done
```

Edit: Thank you Barmar! 
It's closer, but not working. What I did to get the closest result was:

```
sub encode_base58sp {
    my $in = shift;
    my $out = '';
    my @base58 = (1 .. 9, 'A' .. 'H', 'J' .. 'N', 'P' .. 'Z', 'a' .. 'k', 'm' .. 'z');
    my $n = hex($in);
    while ($n > 1) {
       my $remain = $n % 58;
       $out = $base58[$remain] . $out;
       $n /= 58;
    }
    return $out;
}
```

With that I get the first 9 chars okay, but the rest is wrong...
Any Idea?

Comment: Can you supply sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 2):

```
use bignum; # Get arbitrary precision arithmetic

# base58=({1..9} {A..H} {J..N} {P..Z} {a..k} {m..z})
my @base58 = (1 .. 9, 'A' .. 'H', 'J' .. 'N', 'P' .. 'Z', 'a' .. 'k', 'm' .. 'z');
# ibase=16; n=${1^^};
my $n = hex($ARGV[0]);
# while(n>0)
my $result = "";
while ($n > 0) {
  # n%3A, tac, and echo ${base58[n]} (hex 3A == dec 58)
  $result = $base58[$n % 58] . $result;
  # n/=3A
  $n /= 58;
}
print "$result\n";
```

Comment: You can simplify the list as `(1 .. 9, 'A' .. 'H', 'J' .. 'N', 'P' .. 'Z', 'a' .. 'k', 'm' .. 'z')`.

Comment: Good point. But then you can't use the `qw(...)` simplification, can you?

Comment: True. Perhaps a thing of individual preference.

Comment: I'm going with the `..` notation, as it makes it clearer that you're skipping some letters.

Comment: Ahh, forgot to translate `tac`, which reverses everything. Give me a minute.

Comment: Check my edit. First 9 chars = ok, the rest of the output is different. Any Idea to solve it?

Comment: I suspect the issue is that `bc` supports unlimited precision of integers, but you have to use a multi-precision module to do it with perl.

Comment: Added `use bignum;` pragma, see if that helps.

Comment: If you're using perl older than 5.9.4 you need to change the declaration to `use bignum 'hex'` so that the `hex()` function will be overridden. Other than that, I'm not sure why this wouldn't work now. I suggest you look at the perl bignum documentation and see if you can find issues.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Barmar,

It worked with "use bigrat;" (Transparent BigNumber/BigRational support for Perl).

Here's the solution (sub based on your translation):

```
 sub encode_Base58Check {
    use bigrat;
    my $in = shift;
    my $out = '';
    my @base58 = (1 .. 9, 'A' .. 'H', 'J' .. 'N', 'P' .. 'Z', 'a' .. 'k', 'm' .. 'z');
    my $n = hex($in);
    while ($n > 1) {
       $out = $base58[$n % 58] . $out;
       $n /= 58;
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Thank you!